# 16.04 Ubuntu Installing Arial over SSH

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I am trying to install Arial on a Ubuntu server over SSH. 
I tried to use `sudo apt-get install tff-mscorefonts-installer`.

But all I get is

> Unable to locate package tff-mscorefonts-installer.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

You’re looking for

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

(not `tff-...`).